# find the rank of the matrix if, is my answer right?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if $$  B =
\pmatrix{-3&-2&1 \\ 1&0&1\\0&-4&8\\0&1&-2 \\3&0&3}\   \
$$

if $C(B)$=$N(A)$  then find the rank of matrix A ?

the answer will be as follow

$C(B)=2$

Rank of $B=2$

$N(B)=3-2=1$

$N(A)=2$

the rank $=$ number of columns $-$ the nullity

then 
rank of A $=$ number of columns $-$ 2

the problem is that iam not sure about the number of A columns is it 3?

if it is then the rank of $A = 1$

if it not then any help on that and thank you in advance

Comment: What does $C(B)$ mean? How are $A$ and $B$ related?

Comment: @Theo Bendit $C(B)$ all linear combination of of columns of B, they related by the relation $C(B)=N(A)$

Comment: In that case, I would refrain from referring to $C(B)$ as a number, as it is a space of vectors. You could talk about $\operatorname{dim} C(B)$ as a number, but this is precisely $\operatorname{rank} B$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit $C(B)$ as number it is the number of independent columns of B which is 2 and rank also is 2

Comment: These are different concepts! If $C(B)$ is the set of all linear combinations of columns of $B$, then it is a space of vectors. If it is the number of linearly independent columns of $B$, then it is a number (the dimension of this subspace). The latter number is the definition of "rank". There's nothing wrong with using alternative names for the rank, but it's confusing when you refer both to $C(B)$ and $\operatorname{rank} B$ in the same argument!

Comment: @Theo Bendit your right i think i got it mixed it is as you said, thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of columns of $A$ must be $5$. You can tell this from the nullspace of $A$, which is the columnspace of $B$. Note that the columnspace of $B$ consists of vectors with $5$ components, and $A$ must multiply to each of these vectors (to produce the $0$ vector). In order for this multiplication to be well-defined, the number of columns of $A$ must be $5$.

Hence,

$$5 = \operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{nullity} A = \operatorname{rank} A + 2 \implies \operatorname{rank} A = 3.$$

Comment: thank you very much for explaining to me i was very confused about that and now it is clear thanks again